# jQuery how to change img src path onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basicly what I want to make is everytime you click on an image outside of the div "img-container" it changes the src path in "img-container" div. Came this far, now I don't know how to finish this code.

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img id="changeMe" src="">
</div>

<img src="images/preview-1.jpg">
<img src="images/preview-2.jpg">
<img src="images/preview-2.jpg">

$('img').click(function(event) {
   alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give them a class

```
<div class="img-container">
  <img id="changeMe" src="">
</div>

<img class="preview" src="images/preview-1.jpg">
<img class="preview" src="images/preview-2.jpg">
<img class="preview" src="images/preview-2.jpg">
```

Then do

```
$('.preview').on('click',  function() {
    $('#changeMe').prop('src', this.src);
});
```

Comment: Works great, just what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

no need to change the markup
just change script as follow

```
$('img:not(div img)').click(function(event) {
  $(".img-container img").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: It's changing the src path of it, but not the width / height. And that's very important...That's the only problem I got.

Comment: i guess  the image container to show all image has some width and height style if it's true

then you must set them in you script explicit

Answer (score 0):

Adneneos' answer is the most efficient.

However, this method would be good if, for some reason, you can't add classes to the images. This uses the [.each() method](http://api.jquery.com/each/)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("img[id!='changeMe']").each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
   $("#changeMe").attr('src', this.src);
  });
 });
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s4wbnow6/)

EDIT: You would need to define a more specific of sorts, because this method would check every image on the page. This answer is based on the code provided. However, adeneos answer may be easier.

Comment: I agree that adneneos answer is the most efficient.